# Different Prometheus scrape URL for every target

Tags: prometheus

Every instance of my application has a different URL. 
How can I configure prometheus.yml so that it takes path of a target along with the host name?

```
scrape_configs:
- job_name:       'example-random'

# Override the global default and scrape targets from this job every 5 seconds.
scrape_interval: 5s

static_configs:
  - targets: ['localhost:8090','localhost:8080']
    labels:
      group: 'dummy'
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You currently can't configure the `metrics_path` per target within a job but you can create separate jobs for each of your targets so you can define `metrics_path` per target.

Your config file would look something like this:

```
scrape_configs:
- job_name:       'example-target-1'
  scrape_interval: 5s
  metrics_path: /target-1-path-to-metrics
  static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:8090']
      labels:
        group: 'dummy'

- job_name:       'example-target-2'
  scrape_interval: 5s
  metrics_path: /totally-different-path-for-target-2
  static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:8080']
      labels:
        group: 'dummy-2'
```

Comment: Is there any valid reason why this feature is not implemented ? it's a common use case

Answer (score 25):

I achieved this by using [file_sd_config](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#file_sd_config) option. All targets are described in separate file(s), which can be either in YML or JSON format.

**prometheus.yml**:

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'dummy'  # This will be overridden in targets.yml
    file_sd_configs:
      - files:
        - targets.yml
```

**targets.yml**:

```
- targets: ['host1:9999']
  labels:
    job: my_job
    __metrics_path__: /path1

- targets: ['host2:9999']
  labels:
    job: my_job  # can belong to the same job
    __metrics_path__: /path2
```

Comment: You can use **__metrics_path__** without **file_sd_configs**, just in the **static_configs**

Answer (score 7):

This is the configuration I used to get prometheus up and running.

Prometheus Endpoint : `http://localhost:8080/appcontext/v1/actuator/prometheus`

Configuration: Add the below config under `/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml`

```
- job_name: 'appdev'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    metrics_path: /appcontext/v1/actuator/prometheus
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:8082'] 
        labels:
          group: 'appdev'
```

Comment: Why this Prometheus Endpoint is running on port 8080, but target is on 8082. It don't have to be the same?

Answer (score 6):

I believe you need to do some relabelling of the `__metrics_path__` label set to include the varying paths of your applications.

The Prometheus [configuration docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/operating/configuration/#relabel_config) will prove useful to you here and [this article](https://www.robustperception.io/life-of-a-label/) should help you understand relabelling a little better.

Comment: Thanks to your comment, i solved my problem of updating scrape URL on fly. Too bad it is hidden under complex explanations in the docs while i think this should be clearly stated as a feature.

Comment: For people who want an example, here is one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59866342/prometheus-dynamic-metrics-path